# RefTex theorem-type environments

Tags: reftex-mode

Following discussions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60957/74050) and documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Theorem-and-Axiom.html), I tried to customize my `init.el` in other to add my own way of managine envs. I put up this code

```
(setq reftex-label-alist
      '(("theorem"     ?T  "stm:"   "~\\ref{%s}"  t   ("theorem"))
    ("proposition" ?T  "stm:"   "~\\ref{%s}"  t   ("proposition"))
    ("lemma"       ?T  "stm:"   "~\\ref{%s}"  t   ("lemma"))
    ("corollary"   ?T  "stm:"   "~\\ref{%s}"  t   ("corollary"))
    ("axiom"       ?T  "ax:"    "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("axiom"))
        ("assumption"  ?T  "asm:"   "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("assumption"))
    ("definition"  ?T  "def:"   "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("definition"))
        ("condition"   ?T  "cnd:"   "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("condition"))
    ("example"     ?T  "ex:"    "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("example"))
    ("remark"      ?T  "rmk:"   "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("remark"))
    ("algorithm"   ?E  "algo:"  "~\\ref{%s}"   t   ("algorithm"))
    ))
;; 
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (LaTeX-add-environments
         '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("proposition" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("lemma" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("corollary" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("axiom" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("assumption" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("definition" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("condition" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("example" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("remark" LaTeX-env-label)
         '("algorithm" LaTeX-env-label)
         )))
```

However, the behavior of emacs+reftex is clear to me. For example, if i put this

```
\begin{theorem}%% position A
statement
\end{therem}
```

with the cursor in "*position A*" I do `C-c (`, the label generator creates a correct label `\label{stm:1}`. But for the other envs things are mixed. For example for

```
\begin{assumption}%% position B
statement
\end{assumption}
```

with the cursor in "*position B*" when I do `C-c (` I am pompted to `\label{sec:}` whic is supposed to be for section.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code

Comment: Do you really mean `\label{stm:1}`?  From yr code, it should be `\label{stm1:1}`, no?

Comment: Looks like you are only allowed one label per type so all the envs of type `?T` get `"stm1:"` but the env of type `?E`  gets `"algo"`.

Comment: @Fran Burstall: oh thanks,  I copied a different version of the code. I corrected my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *@Fran Burstall** 
_second issue:_ I checked your intuition and you are right. My intention was to create an env type `T` so that when using `C-c (` selecting the type `T` I had all obecjts obtained with `\newtheorem`of _amsthm_ package. Like when you do `C-c (` and select `e`, then you get all equetion-related stuff.